# How to fix track not rendering in Star Wars Episode I Racer?

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card, windows-xp, star-wars-episode-i-racer

I installed a CD-ROM of *Star Wars Episode I: Racer*, for PC, on a computer running Windows XP. Though the graphics cards, Intel GMA 4500MHD, aren't really new, they should be sufficient, in fact, it plays many other 3D games fine. But for some reason when I start a race, only the podracer and HUD are visible, the actual landscape ahead of the podracer isn't rendered, is just white. If I drive ahead, I can still crash into things, and can see those things that are within a few feet of the racer, but no further in front of me on the track.

Comment: I my first guess would be the grahphics card driver. You could try to installing the latest available driver that supports that graphics card. Maybe trying to do a clean removal of the old driver first with something like [DDU](https://graphicscardhub.com/display-driver-uninstaller-ddu/). It claims to still support WinXP.

Comment: Yes, I have installed the custom graphics card that is provided by the manufacturer of the laptop.